# Layout in AVD not the same as ADT?

Tags: android, eclipse

I don't see it but the layout on AVD isn't the same as what i expected based on ADT. I have one image button 1/3 and one regular button which should be 2/3 of the width.
I created a realtivelayout and for the buttons a linearlayout, why is the layout in ADT en AVD not the same and how can i fix this?

[image: This is what i designed in ADT]

and this is the AVD

[image: on the AVD it's not 1/3 of the screen]

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textHeaderView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageQuoteView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="@string/textHeaderQuote"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="24sp" />    

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/viewQuote"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textHeaderView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:text="@string/textViewQuote"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"
    >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnShare"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#CCCCCC"
    android:contentDescription="@string/btnsharetext"
    android:onClick="shareQuote"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSendQuote"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:onClick="sendQuotePage"
    android:text="@string/btn_text_sendQuote"
    android:background="#FEFEFE" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: are both screens the same size?

Comment: @robin sorry what do you mean? AVD is just the virtual screen of the ADT screen, right?

Answer (score 1):

An AVD(Android virtual device) has ofcourse its screen size and resulution. In the ADT(Android development tool) you can select a screen for your layout, just above the screen layout. Default is Nexus one. Try to set an other screen and see what happens.

Comment: i have even tried "preview all screens" and the layout in ADT is as expected. On AVD and Samsung s3 the buttons aren't covering the width of the screen.

Comment: In your image i can see you have not set a width. Use fill_parent to cover the width of the screen

Answer (score 1):

Set a margin for you linear layout. For example:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"

    android:layout_margin="5dp">
```

As to why the ADT display simulation differs from the AVD; the ADT dialog you see is a quick representation of what it can look like --not what it will absolutely look like.  The AVD is an emulator of a physical device meaning that it will give you the most accurate view.

**EDIT:** Actually answering your question

As for you button widths, you need to set their relative widths using weight for the parent layout, as well as specify widths of 0.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:paddingLeft="0dp"

    android:layout_weight="3">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnShare"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#CCCCCC"
    android:contentDescription="@string/btnsharetext"
    android:onClick="shareQuote"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share" 

    android:layout_width="0dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSendQuote"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:onClick="sendQuotePage"
    android:text="@string/btn_text_sendQuote"
    android:background="#FEFEFE" 

    android:layout_width="0dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Personally I don't use the Auto-Layout tools (ADT) that they offer since they don't give you much freedom.